# Access forbidden after changing Apache root in httpd.config to Dropbox

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, dropbox

I'm trying to change the Apache root directory from

```
/Users/"my user"/applications/XAMPP/htdocs
```

to a

```
/Users/"my user"/dropbox/sites
```

directory, so that my files automatically back up to Dropbox. However, after restarting the server within XAMPP I am getting an **"Access denied! There is no index...."** error.

- Macbook Pro, OSX Mavericks
- XAMPP latest edition

here is my https.conf, part regarding the document root:

```
# DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "/Users/edchigliak/dropbox/sites"
<Directory "/Users/edchigliak/dropbox/sites">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
# XAMPP
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
#AllowOverride None
# since XAMPP 1.4:
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

As you can see I just commented the first line # DocumentRoot, copied it into the next line and changed the path. Below that, I also copied the right path wanting to grant permissions to the new root directory. SOmething has gone wrong along the way :))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The user that Apache is running under won't have access to the home directory of a specific user by default, you'll need to grant that access for this to work.

Comment: A-ha! That is the problem... Can you help out with the directives/code? I really do very little server administration, if any so I'm not really knowledgeable on this. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexStarbuck I'm not sure exactly how that needs to look on an OS X server, but, it looks like you'll need to grant the `_www` user access to the directory - seems like something you'd be able to do in the permissions UI, or do something like [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151198/how-do-i-grant-a-second-user-complete-access-to-a-users-home-folder).